# using button how to Scroll to selected div in angular 6

Tags: angular5, angular6, angular2-forms

Hi i'am using Angular6 in this if i click the button it should scroll to selected   div. for this i have used npm install ng2-scroll-to --save plugin but  button selector was not working  please help me to do this. if there any alternate solution also just tell me.

```
<a scrollTo href="#main-section">Scroll to main section</a>
        <button scrollTo scrollTargetSelector="#test-section">Scroll to test section</button >
        <button scrollTo scrollableElementSelector="#container" scrollYTarget="0">Go top</button >
        <!-- Further content here -->
        <div id="container">
            <section id="main-section">Bla bla bla</section>
            <section id="test-section">Bla bla bla</section>
        <div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import ScroolModule to app module

```
// app.module.ts
import {ScrollToModule} from 'ng2-scroll-to';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         ....,
        ScrollToModule.forRoot(),
        ]
})
```

After that it should be fine.